# HTML number input validation for strictly greater than

Tags: html, validation, input, min

```
<input type="number" min="3" step="0.01"/>
```

For this input, if the user enters 3, it will pass.
I want 3 to fail but 3.01 to pass.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can't you set `min` to `3.01`?

Comment: That is one way. But then the error message says: "value must be 3.01 or higher". I'd prefer "Value must be higher than 3"

Comment: There is also setCustomValidity javascript method, but that requires some coding. I would prefer to handle it with pure html attributes.